# SQL creating and interacting with three tables

Tags: sql

So here is what I'm playing around with: Let's simulate an e-commerce site. We're going to need users, products, and orders.

- Users need a name and an email.
- Products need a name and a price
- Orders need a ref to product.

All 3 need primary keys.

---

*Instructions*

- Create 3 tables following the criteria in the summary. Add some data to fill up each table - at least 3 users, 3 products, 3 orders.
- Run queries against your data: Get all products for the first order; Get all orders; Get the total cost of an order ( sum the price of all products on an order ).
- Add a foreign key reference from orders to users and update the orders table to link a user to each order.
- Run further queries against your data: Get all orders for a user; Get how many orders each user has.

Can somebody with a little time on their hands write out what this would look like. I would be forever grateful is someone could write this out so I could study it, get past this problem and see how this is done. Here's what I have so far:

```
   CREATE TABLE orders (
     order_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
     stuff VARCHAR(150),
     product_id INTEGER REFERENCES products(product_id)
     );
    
  INSERT INTO users (name, email)
    VALUES
    ('Justin', 'Justinjgh@gmail.com'),
    ('Bill', 'Bill@gmail.com'),
    ('Rick', 'Rick@gmail.com');
  
  INSERT INTO products (name, price)
    VALUES
    ('Chair', 22),
    ('Turkey', 10),
    ('Lizard', 10000);
  
  INSERT INTO orders (stuff, product_id)
    VALUES
    ('Testthis', 1),
    ('Testthat', 2),
    ('Andtestthis', 3);
  
  SELECT * FROM products
    WHERE product_id = 1;
  
  SELECT * FROM orders;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not going to answer your whole question (it looks like homework) but I'll give you some help to get over this hump.

To start with, your Users and Products tables look pretty reasonable. You could add keys to them (numbers, or barcode_IDs, or whatever) to deal with ambiguous situations. But the tables are basically correct - each row holds the info about 1 of the things e.g.,

- Each row in the Users table refers to 1 user and their properties (email address)
- This is also true for Products (each line is one product, with its name and price).

Now, onto Orders. You're halfway there but take another look at the fields in it.

- Order_ID... that's OK
- Stuff... not sure what's in here
- Product_id... what? This implies that each order can have 1, and only 1, product. This seems strange - in real life an order should be able to have multiple products, wouldn't it?

Instead, I would suggest something where there's a many-to-many relationship between Orders and Products - each Order can have multiple different products (and the same product can be on different orders).

There also seems to be something missing - the relationship between Users and Orders. What is the relationship here? 1-to-1? 1 user per Order? Multiple users per Order? So there is a link to be built in to help you there.

Once you've answered those two questions, your initial question is answered (sort of). However, you may then want to think about next steps

- Think about buying stuff online. Your total price is the sum of the cost of all your items. But you can have multiple of the same item (e.g., 12 bottles of your favorite drink). You may want to think how those link.